# Compiler error when trying to sort an array of char[16]

Tags: c++, sorting

How can `std::sort` be used to sort a fixed size array (e.g. `typedef XXX char[16]`)?
I tried a few things, but it does not seem to work. E.g. my current code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

typedef char t_name[16];

bool compareNames(const t_name& name1, const t_name& name2) {
    return strcmp(name1, name2) < 0;
}

int main() {
    t_name names[] = {
        "bruno",
        "karl",
        "adrian",
        "yanick"
    };

    int numNames = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    std::sort(names, names + numNames, compareNames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        std::cout << names[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile. Likely, because the normal assignment does not work for array-types. The error (which is not so readable) an be seen here:
https://godbolt.org/z/Ms54P7ozj

Maybe someone has an idea how this can be achieved? Unfortunately, I have no control over the array-type which I want to sort, so that cannot be changed.

Comment: *Unfortunately, this code does not compile* -- You should post the compiler error.

Comment: What resources are you using to learn C++? It seems to teach you more C and not so much C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I've added a link to godbolt, but the error is not so nice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As noted in the question, I do not have control over this type, so no sure what you want to tell me.

Comment: *the normal assignment does not work for array-types* -- Thus it cannot be used in `std::sort`, since the type needs to be [Move assignable / constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  The usage of `std::array` instead of dumb C-style arrays would alleviate this issue, plus you wouldn't need to write a compare function.

Comment: [Just a change to std::array results in the correct output](https://godbolt.org/z/Gfcj6zzna).

Comment: Arrays instead of `std::string`, `strcmp`, plain arrays instead of `std::array` or `std::vector`, `sizeof` to get the array size, `typedef` for type-aliases... Few C++ programmers would call that "proper" C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The problem is I cannot change the typedef, because it's from a C library :/

Comment: Regarding errors, please include them in the question itself, copy-pasted as text. Please keep questions self-contained. Links to external sites can "rot", and make your question useless.

Comment: @KevinMeier -- You can wrap that type in a `struct` and `std::sort` and array of that struct.  So the change is either to the type, or you stick that type in a container that *can* be sorted using `std::sort`.

Comment: If you can't change anything to make it compatible with `std::sort` there's always `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a proof-of-concept that you can sort the char arrays in the original `names` array using a proper wrapper, without resorting to `std::string` or `std::string_view` or changing your existing data structure. However, use the solution in one of the other answers if by all means possible because they are much better and more canonical approaches to the problem if you were not restricted by the typedef.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

typedef char t_name[16];

t_name buffer = "";

struct wrapper{
    t_name* pName = &buffer;
    wrapper(t_name& name):pName{&name}{}
    wrapper(const wrapper& other){
        std::copy(std::begin(*other.pName), std::end(*other.pName), std::begin(*pName));
    }
    wrapper& operator=(const wrapper& other){
        if(this == &other)
            return *this;
        std::copy(std::begin(*other.pName), std::end(*other.pName), std::begin(*pName));
        return *this;
    }
};

void swap(wrapper& a, wrapper& b){
    std::swap_ranges(std::begin(*a.pName), std::end(*a.pName), std::begin(*b.pName));
}

bool compareNames(const wrapper& w1, const wrapper& w2) {
    return std::strcmp(*w1.pName, *w2.pName) < 0;
}

int main() {
    t_name names[] = {
        "bruno",
        "karl",
        "adrian",
        "yanick"
    };

    int numNames = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);
    std::vector<wrapper> wrapped{std::begin(names), std::end(names)};

    std::sort(wrapped.begin(), wrapped.end(), compareNames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        std::cout << names[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/77GdPGx9x

Answer (score 3):

You can't [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) a range of C-style arrays because they doesn't satisfy the type requirements:

- the element has to be [*ValueSwappable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) (OK, arrays satisfy this because [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) has an overload for arrays)
- the element has to be [*MoveAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) and [*MoveConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible) (NOT OK, arrays aren't assignable at all)

You could solve this problem by sorting an array of [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead:

```cpp
// also consider using std::array instead of C-style arrays
std::string_view names[] = {
    // with std::string_view, we still get nice initialization syntax
    // (unlike if we initialized an array of std::array)
    "bruno",
    "karl",
    "adrian",
    "yanick"
};

// no custom comparator needed
std::sort(std::begin(names), std::end(names));

// alternatively, since C++20
std::ranges::sort(names);
```

*Note 1: Prior to C++17, you could use `std::string` instead of `std::string_view` instead.*

*Note 2: you can still provide a custom comparator. If you want to sort in descending order instead, provide [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) / [`std::ranges::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/greater) for example.*

Answer (score 1):

###### Wrap `t_name` in a `struct`

Here is the wrapper solution suggested by @PaulMcKenzie in his comment. Paul beat me to the punch. I was coding this at the time he posted.

In a comment below his question, the OP explains that `t_name` comes from a library, and that he has no control over it. That means `std::string` or `std::string_view` are just not options for him.

Wrapping `t_name` in a struct does get you the sorting capability the OP asks about. You can create built-in arrays of `t_name_struct`, and use `std::sort` with them.

If, however, the library being used by the OP requires him to interface with a built-in array of `t_name`, rather than individual `t_name` objects one at a time, then this solution is problematic. In that case, some method for transforming from one array type to the other would be needed.

With those caveats, there are also some advantages that come from using a wrapper such as `t_name_struct`.

One nice thing about using a struct is that you can define `operator<` to handle the comparisons. That allows you to omit the comparator in the call to `sort`.

Since the array definition is available in the same scope as the call to `sort`, you can use `std::begin(names)` and `std::end(names)` to get iterators for the array. I have used those in the call to `sort`.

For the same reason, you can use *range-for* to loop over the elements of the array. That way, you need not include a calculation for `numNames`. By the way, when you do need the size of a built-in array, you can now use `std::size` to get it. `sizeof` returns the number of bytes; `std::size`, the number of elements.

All in all, the whole thing cleans up nicely.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

typedef char t_name[16];

struct t_name_struct
{
    t_name name;
    bool operator< (t_name_struct const& that) const noexcept {
        return std::strcmp(this->name, that.name) < 0;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost, t_name_struct const& t) {
        ost << t.name;
        return ost;
    }
};

int main() {
    t_name_struct names[] = {
        "bruno",
        "karl",
        "adrian",
        "yanick"
    };
    std::sort(std::begin(names), std::end(names));
    for (auto const& n : names)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
adrian
bruno
karl
yanick
```

###### Using the spaceship `operator<=>`

If C++20 is available, you can replace `operator<` with the spaceship `operator<=>`. Given the three-way nature of `strcmp`, it is natural to write a spaceship operator for it.

```cpp
struct t_name_struct
{
    t_name name;
    auto operator<=> (t_name_struct const& that) const noexcept {
        return std::strcmp(this->name, that.name) <=> 0;
    }
    //... 
};
```

Comment: Your implementation looks better, so I deleted my post.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef char t_name[16];
```

Means that all your strings have be exactly 15 characters long plus a null char. I suppose we could fix it by padding out all the items in the `names` array with sufficient spaces or null chars.  But that's a bit awkward as a declaration.  Since you're dealing with string literals, you're entire program (including it's mix of C and C++ patterns) can be just this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


bool compareNames(const char* name1, const char* name2) {
    return strcmp(name1, name2) < 0;
}

int main() {
    const char* names[] = {
        "bruno",
        "karl",
        "adrian",
        "yanick"
    };

    int numNames = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    std::sort(names, names + numNames, compareNames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        std::cout << names[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And now to make it more C++ like, we can leverage std::string and then take advantage that std::string has a built-in `<` operator overload. Then we don't need an explicit comparison function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string names[] = {
        "bruno",
        "karl",
        "adrian",
        "yanick"
    };

    int numNames = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    std::sort(names, names + numNames);

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        std::cout << names[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But if you were doing something custom, like sorting in descending order instead of ascending, you could do this with a lambda:

```
    std::sort(names, names + numNames, [](const std::string& s1, const std::string &s2) {
        return s1 > s2;
    });
```